# DotNetOpenAuth OAuth2Client Add custom header in TokenEndpoint Request

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, dotnetopenauth

The oAuth2 server I am integrating with requires a header ("Accept: application/json") in the Access Token Request that is performed by ProcessUserAuthentication

```
// In callback from initial RequestUserAuthorization
using DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth2;
var server = new AuthorizationServerDescription
            {
                AuthorizationEndpoint = new System.Uri("APPROVE-APP-ENDPOINT"),
                TokenEndpoint = new System.Uri("MY-TOKEN-ENDPOINT"),
                ProtocolVersion = ProtocolVersion.V20
            };
var client = new WebServerClient(server,CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET);
var authorization = client.ProcessUserAuthorization();
```

So how can I add this header into the request to the TokenEndpoint that is called as part of ProcessUserAuthorization (where the Authorization token is exchanged for an Access/Refresh token)?

Comment: Did you manage to do this. i am having same type of issue. i need to set custom header for client.

Comment: Sorry - didn't get this working and tackled it a different way. DotnetOpenAuth... urgh... infact oAuth in general .... urghhh

Comment: Even i was not able to set custom headers using dotnetopenauth. finally i found library and modified https://github.com/ghorsey/SharpOAuth2/tree/master/code/src/SharpOAuth2.Framework and change according to my requriment